# Can't import Numpy from a zip file: "No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Because of certain requirements, I have to import non-standard python libraries from a zip file one level up. I made it work with Sympy, but I had no luck with numpy.

I use `pip install numpy --target=.\somefolder --no-user` to install numpy in some folder so I zip it.
This is the code I have to use according to the documentation of my platform.

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname
(os.path.realpath(__file__))), "numpy.zip"))
```

My program works when I install it locally, but not when imported from the zip file. I've experimented with various versions and am currently attempting with Python 3.7.9 (preferred) and Numpy 1.19.3. However, I sometimes encounter the following error:

```
 File "c:\...\numpy.zip\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 1132
    def putmask(a, /, mask, values):
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Or

```
No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

What steps can I take to successfully import numpy from a zip file? I have the following folders in the zip: bin, numpy and numpy-1.19.3.dist-info.